# postman - locking random value, same value for every test in same collection

Tags: random, postman

Is there a way to 'lock' random value in postman? I would like to generate one random value and use same value for every test in same collection.

this code generate different random value for every test:

```
pm.environment.set("random", _.random(0,9999999));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you use this in the pre-request:

```
let randomNum = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomInt}}")

pm.variables.set("randomNum", randomNum)
```

Then use `{{randomNum}}` in the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem was setting global variable in 'pre-request script' only for first request of the collection, and leaving 'pre-request script' empty for every next request:

```
pm.globals.set("randomNum", _.random(0,9999999));
```

But thanks for your comment anyway @Danny Dainton. I should use 'request' instead of 'test' in my question. What probably misleaded your thinking.